# Convert .txt file to .csv with header by using bash

Tags: bash, unix

I need a bash script to get the values from .txt file and put it in .csv file ,from the below response i needed two values TestStep and Messages
       As well as i have too many .txt files from all the files i need to pick this two values and put it in a single .csv

```
    Status: FAILED
    Time Taken: 913
    Size: 301
    Timestamp: Thu Aug 18 14:35:17 IST 2016
    TestStep: Enroll User to a Class without filling fields

    ----------------- Messages ------------------------------
    [Contains] Missing token [Learnerid is required] in Response
    [Contains 1] Missing token [Courseid is required] in Response
    [Contains 2] Missing token [Classid is required] in Response

    ----------------- Properties ------------------------------
    StatusCode: 200
    Method: GET
    HTTP Version: HTTP/1.1
    Endpoint: https://qa01.exphosted.com
    URL: https://qa01.exphosted.com/apis/ext/ExpertusOneAPI.php?userid=1&Display+Columns=id%2Cuserid%2Cstatus&returntype=xml&apiname=AddRosterAPI
```

Sample Output should be like in csv file:

TestStep Messages

```
    -
```

Comment: add expected output for sample input.... may be add two sample input files and add expected output for that..

Comment: yes  add sample input and what you want result

Comment: Sample Output should be like in csv file:

TestStep Messages

Comment: let it be duplicate,please help me out?

Comment: you have not provided a sample output. Have you tried the methods described in the duplicate question ?